# Mail doesn't work in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, email

So I'm trying to launch mail() function in PHP, so I installed mail (mailutilities as well) package into my debian server. When I'm trying to send the email I don't get it.

Here's what log says:

```
May 23 22:22:50 raspberrypi sm-msp-queue[1299]: My unqualified host name (raspberrypi) unknown; sleeping for retry
May 23 22:23:16 raspberrypi sendmail[1530]: My unqualified host name (raspberrypi) unknown; sleeping for retry
May 23 22:23:59 raspberrypi sm-mta[819]: unable to qualify my own domain name (raspberrypi) -- using short name
May 23 22:23:59 raspberrypi sm-mta[1534]: starting daemon (8.14.4): SMTP+queueing@00:10:00
May 23 22:24:00 raspberrypi sm-msp-queue[1299]: unable to qualify my own domain name (raspberrypi) -- using short name
May 23 22:24:16 raspberrypi sendmail[1530]: unable to qualify my own domain name (raspberrypi) -- using short name
May 23 22:24:16 raspberrypi sendmail[1530]: v4NJOGSk001530: from=www-data, size=239, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<2017052319                                               24.v4NJOGSk001530@raspberrypi>, relay=www-data@localhost
May 23 22:24:16 raspberrypi sm-mta[1553]: v4NJOGcp001553: from=<www-data@raspberrypi>, size=458, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid                                               =<201705231924.v4NJOGSk001530@raspberrypi>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]to
May 23 22:24:17 raspberrypi sendmail[1530]: v4NJOGSk001530: to=hiding_my_real_emailgmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), dela                                               y=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30239, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v4NJOGcp001553                                                Message accepted for delivery)
```

My email box keeps being empty. Do I need to configure SMTP server on my server or smth?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to configure SMTP server on my server or smth?

Yes. Either that or configure PHP to send mail using a third-party provider.